# Knockout changes the value of one variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Im am trying to edit one user in knockout, but this happends, i got the element and i send that in a query to Controler, that return my (object) in JSON
i save that object in this variable:

```
var ViewUsuarios = function () {
     self.dato = ko.observableArray();
      var usuariosUri = '/api/Usuarios/';
      var rolesUri = 'api/Rols/';

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error('');
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        //Strinfy convierte una cadena de tipo javascript a objetos tipo JSON
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

}

all works fine, but when i do this:

```
 ajaxHelper(usuariosUri + item.ID, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        self.upUsuario(data); <- Here i have the user
    });

    ajaxHelper(rolesUri + item.RolId,'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.dato(data); <- Here works i have the correct ROL
        alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Correcto ");
    });
        alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Incorrecto"); <- Here don't work at first click is null and second have the after element
```

i don't know where is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because:

- `alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Incorrecto");` is called synchronously.
- `self.dato(data); alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Correcto ");` is called asynchronously.

---

So the actual execution order is:

1. `ajaxHelper(usuariosUri + item.ID, 'GET')`
2. `ajaxHelper(rolesUri + item.RolId,'GET')`
3. `alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Incorrecto");`
4. `self.upUsuario(data);` or
   `self.dato(data); alert(JSON.stringify(self.dato())+"Correcto ");`

`self.dato` will be never initialized until 4, although 3 refers `self.dato`.
That's why `self.dato` is empty on the first click.
Maybe on the second click, `self.dato` contains previous result of `ajaxHelper`.

Comment: thanks, and how i can do for get the correct rol, or in what order cand i put that?

Comment: The callback of `ajaxHelper` contains the correct result.
It may not be correct until the callback.

Comment: Thanks i can fix that. You were right about asynchronosuly.